# Understanding the use of Math.floor when randomly accessing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random, floor

I used a code I found on this site to access an array of string values. I changed the variable names, but other than that, the code remains the same.

```
var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
```

It works, and as I understand it, `(Math.random() * array.length)` is the area which generates the random number itself, so why is `Math.floor` required? I am clearly not understanding something quite obvious here.

Comment: `Math.random` returns a floating number and array elements indexes are actually integers. `Math.floor` rounds the float down to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.floor` returns a whole number, while `Math.random()` will return a float between 0 and 1.

To access an item in an array, like `rand[0]`, you need to have a whole number. You cannot access an item in array with `rand[1.43]`.

That little line of code is going to access a random item in an array by generating a random float from zero to the array's length, and rounding it to its nearest whole number with `Math.floor`

Comment: So, `Math.random()` may produce 0.7, which multiplied by `array.length` (3 in my case), would result in 2.1 - which `Math.floor` would make as 2, meaning the 3rd array value would be accessed. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct! That's the basics of it.

Comment: Thanks man. All the replies were great and more than I could have asked for, but you explained it in a way which made it very easy to understand :)

Answer (score 3):

Because there are no fractional array elements

```js
const array = [123, 456];
console.log(array[0.5]);
```

The code above prints `undefined` because there is no `0.5` element. There is a `0` element and a `1` element but no 0.5 element

So, to choose a random element with `Math.random()` which returns a number between 0 and 1 (but not 1) you have to convert to an integer.

JavaScript arrays are not like arrays in most other languages. They're actually more like augmented objects. They act like arrays in that you can get the length (`array.length`) and call things like push,pop,concat,shift,unshift but you can also add properties

```js
array = [4, 5, 6];
array["foo"] = "bar"
console.log(Object.keys(array));
```

Prints

```
[
  "0",
  "1",
  "2",
  "foo"
]
```

Which explains why the `Math.random` without the `Math.floor` would fail. From the semantic point of view of JavaScript an array is just an object with properties named 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. Of course under the hood that's not what JavaScript does as it would be too slow to implement arrays that way but for the most part arrays act like they are actually just an object with properties named '0', '1', '2' and it's perfectly valid to have properties named '0.00012' etc.

Note, it would actually be faster to do this

```
const rand = array[Math.random() * array.length | 0];
```

The `| 0` is a binary *or* of 0 which the JavaScript spec effectively says the result is converted to an integer before the `|` happens. Note that `| 0` is not the same as `Math.floor`.  `| 0` rounds toward 0 whereas `Math.floor` rounds down.

```
         | 0   Math.floor         
------+------+------------
  2.5 |   2  |   2
  1.5 |   1  |   1
  0.5 |   0  |   0
 -0.5 |   0  |  -1
 -1.5 |  =1  |  -2
 -2.5 |  -2  |  -3
```

Comment: never knew of `| 0`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [10,6,2,11,0];
console.log(array[3]); // output = 11

//Math.random() generates random floating point numbers from 0(inclusive) to 1(exclusive).
//Math.random() * array.length will generate all random numbers from 0 to array.length(exclusive)

var randomNumber = Math.random();
console.log("randomNumber = " + randomNumber); // Say, output = 0.8604458676303853
console.log("randomNumber * array.length = " + randomNumber * array.length); // Say, output = 4.3022293381519265

//To access any element in the array you will need indices starting from 0 to array.length(exclusive)

//var rand = array[randomNumber * array.length];
//Will give error as array cannot access a floating point index

console.log("Math.floor(randomNumber * array.length) = " + Math.floor(randomNumber * array.length)); // Say, output = 4

//Finally,
var rand = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
console.log("rand = ", rand);
```

The floor function will do the following thing for you.

1. It will first round the floating number so that it is a valid index to access.

Overall, `Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)` will take care that the maximum index value is always array.length - 1

The reason is that the max number we will get will always be slightly less than array.length).

So even if Math.random() generates 0.999 and you multiply it with array.length = 5.

Thus, 0.999 * 5 = 4.995 and floor of (4.995) = 4. Constraints satisfied :)

Comment: For your point 2, Math.floor does not do the second thing, Math.random does that by not returning 1. All floor does is round down. For point 1 to be clear floor does not "round" it floors. To round you'd call [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round). Another way to put this `Math.ceil` rounds up, `Math.floor` rounds down, `Math.round` rounds.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I had it in my mind, but I accidently wrote it wrong.